# what kind of RDDs in Spark can be saved to BigQuery table using saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

In the example of [Using the BigQuery Connector with Spark](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example)

```
// Perform word count.
val wordCounts = (tableData
    .map(entry => convertToTuple(entry._2))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _))

// Write data back into a new BigQuery table.
// IndirectBigQueryOutputFormat discards keys, so set key to null.
(wordCounts
     .map(pair => (null, convertToJson(pair)))
     .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf))
```

if I remove the `.reduceByKey(_ + _)` part, then I will have the following error

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$.write(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:107)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1084)
>     ... 46 elided
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Schema has no fields. Table: test_output_40b400dc_1bfe_454a_9aa8_bf9562d54c3f_source
>     at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryUtils.waitForJobCompletion(BigQueryUtils.java:95)
>     at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryHelper.importFromGcs(BigQueryHelper.java:164)
>     at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.output.IndirectBigQueryOutputCommitter.commitJob(IndirectBigQueryOutputCommitter.java:57)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$.write(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:101)
>     ... 53 more

In some cases, I don't use reduceByKey and want to save my RDD in BigQuery.

Comment: can you add the full error? Is that error because the code change you made?

Comment: yes, the error happens only after my code change.

Answer (score 0):

try to work with schema :

```
object Schema {
  def apply(record: JsonObject): Schema = Schema (
      word = record.get ("word").getAsString,
      Count = record.get ("Count").getAsInt
    )
}
case class Schema(word String,
                  Count :Int
                  )
```

and pass this schema like this :

```
wordCounts.map(x=>Schema(x))
```

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.IOException: Schema has no fields` is the error, which means BigQuery is unable to detect schema automatically. If you specify a schema like

```java
List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("word").setType("STRING"));
fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("word_count").setType("INTEGER"));
BigQueryOutputConfiguration.configure(conf, ..., new TableSchema().setFields(fields), ...);
```

You should no longer hit this issue.

I think the reason `.reduceByKey(_ + _)` hides this issue is because:

- [Schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect) will select one random file and scan up to 100 rows of data.
- `tableData` RDD is initially partitioned into many small shards, each of which is insufficient to let BigQuery infer schema automatically.
- `.reduceByKey(_ + _)` repartitions the RDD into bigger shards.

My hunch is that if you replace `.reduceByKey(_ + _)` by `.repartition(2)`, the job should also work without explicitly providing a schema.